Showing that a piecewise function is odd
I'm asked to show that the following piecewise function is odd:
$$
f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        (x+6)^2 \text{, } -6 \leq x < 0\\
        -(x-6)^2 \text{, } 0 \leq x < 6
    \end{cases}
$$
I understand that the function being odd requires that for all $x$ in the domain, $–x$ is in the domain, and that $f(-x) = -f(x)$.
For the first condition, $-6$ is in the domain but $-(-6)=6$ is not. Perhaps it's a typo in the original question. Let's assume that the first condition is met.
I'm mostly confused about the second condition. For $-6 \leq x<0$, $f(–x)$ is $(-x+6)^2$, but on the same domain, $-f(x)=-(x+6)^2$, and $(-x+6)^2 \neq -(x+6)^2$.
However, this function certainly seems odd based on its graph, and further, $f(-x)$ paired with $-6 \leq x<0$ does equal $-f(x)$ paired with $0 \leq x<6$ because $(-x+6)^2=(x-6)^2$. (The same is true for the other parts of the domain.)
What am I missing here? Does it not matter that the domains in the piecewise function don't match up when checking equality of $f(-x)$ and $-f(x)$?

The extra $'('$ in the second line of the definition should be removed. For $-6 \leq x<0$, $f(–x)$ is $-(-x-6)^2$ which is $-f(x)$.

@geetha290krm I fixed the typo, but are you sure your second statement is correct? Is not $f(-x)$ on that domain equal to $(–x+6)^2$?

$-x$ is not in the same domain as $x$.  It goes to the other domain.

For any positive $a\in (0,6)$ we have
$$f(-a)=(-a+6)^2=((-1)(a-6))^2=(a-6)^2=-f(a)$$
and therefore the function is odd.

Also note that for $a \in (-6,0)$ we have

$f(-a)=-(-a-6)^2=-(a+6)^2=-f(a)$
$f(-(-a))=f(a)=(a+6)^2=-((-a)-6)^2=-f(-a)$


Perhaps I'm overthinking this, but what about $a \in (-6,0)$? Is that $f(-(-a))=f(a)=-(a-6)^2=-((-1)(a-6))^2=-(-a+6)^2=-f(-a)$?

In this case $a<0$ then $f(-a)=-(-a-6)^2=-(a+6)^2=-f(a)$.

Note also that since $a<0$ we have $f(-(-a))=f(a)=(a+6)^2=-((-a)-6)^2=-f(-a)$.

Thank you for writing out the other part. The thing I don't understand is why, when $a$ is positive, we use the first case. In other words, why if $a \in (0,6)$ is $f(-a)=(-a+6^2)$, and why, when $a$ is negative, we use the second case, $f(-a)=-(-a-6^2)$. Above, @geetha290krm said "it goes to the other domain." Perhaps my misunderstanding is connected to that.

Simply because when $b=-a>0$, by definition, $f(-a)=f(b)=-(b-6)^2$.
